# Responsive design not working on Windows phone

Tags: css, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, responsive-design, media-queries

I am using responsive design for my site but the css media queries are not working for Windows Phone. I found a solution here http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/ but still is not working for me.

I am using on my header file on html this:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

then I add on the head this js:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        if ("-ms-user-select" in document.documentElement.style && navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
            var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
            msViewportStyle.appendChild(
                document.createTextNode("@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}")
            );
            document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(msViewportStyle);
        }
    })();
    </script>
```

before any other script and last on my css page I have:

```
 @-webkit-viewport{width:device-width}
 @-moz-viewport{width:device-width}
 @-ms-viewport{width:device-width}
 @-o-viewport{width:device-width}
 @viewport{width:device-width}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 599px) {
    @-ms-viewport{
      width:320px;
    }
 }
```

But still I cannot make it work. Does anyone have an idea what could be the problem?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there any reason you have to specifically target the windows phone? Why not just set a media query that targets its specific width?

Comment: I have that but is not working. It works for Android and iPhone, but not for Windows phone. So I was searching a solution for Windows phone particularly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this media queries

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```